# adding border to font is very demanding is there any other option?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Here as shown in the picture , i have added a black border to each letter in a text, works fine but I have around 20k text that is shown in a map. The problem is scrolling the map becomes too slow when i use it.

This is the code to generate the black border

```dart
static List<Shadow> outlinedText(
      {double strokeWidth = 2,
      Color strokeColor = Colors.black,
      int precision = 5}) {
    Set<Shadow> result = HashSet();
    for (int x = 1; x < strokeWidth + precision; x++) {
      for (int y = 1; y < strokeWidth + precision; y++) {
        double offsetX = x.toDouble();
        double offsetY = y.toDouble();
        result.add(Shadow(
            offset: Offset(-strokeWidth / offsetX, -strokeWidth / offsetY),
            color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(
            offset: Offset(-strokeWidth / offsetX, strokeWidth / offsetY),
            color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(
            offset: Offset(strokeWidth / offsetX, -strokeWidth / offsetY),
            color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(
            offset: Offset(strokeWidth / offsetX, strokeWidth / offsetY),
            color: strokeColor));
      }
    }
    return result.toList();
  }

  Future<void> loadWayPointsMarkers() async {
    double markerWidth = 5;
    double markerHeight = 5;
    const width = 3.0, height = 3.0;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 10,
      shadows: outlinedText(strokeColor: const Color.fromARGB(137, 40, 38, 38)),
      letterSpacing: 1,
    );

    // Load the JSON file containing the markers
    final String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Waypoints.json');
    // Decode the JSON data into a List of Maps
    final List<dynamic> jsonData = await json.decode(jsonString);
    // Create a List of Markers from the JSON data
    List<MarkerX> wayPointRouteM = jsonData.map((data) {
      final String identifier = data["identifier"];
      final double latitude = data['latitude'];
      final double longitude = data['longitude'];
      final String code = data['country_code'];
      final textSpan = TextSpan(
          text: identifier, style: textStyle, recognizer: _longPressRecognizer);
      final textPainter =
          TextPainter(text: textSpan, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
            ..textScaleFactor = 1.0;
      return MarkerX(
        point: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        onDraw: (canvas, offset) {
          canvas.drawCircle(offset + const Offset(0, height), 2, paint);

          textPainter.layout();
          textPainter.paint(
              canvas,
              offset +
                  Offset(-textPainter.width / 2,
                      -textPainter.height - height - 2));
        },
        width: markerWidth,
        height: markerHeight,
        identifier: identifier,
      );
    }).toList();
    print(wayPointRouteM.length);

    setState(() {
      wayPointsMarkers = wayPointRouteM;
    });
  }
```

The for loop that is embedded in the code make its demanding, i tried many custom fonts but none will show a black border in a white text, Is there any font present that will do the trick ?
Else how can i optimize my code ?

Comment: You can try using ThemeExtension to do it.